# перебор файлов(1.fits, 2.fits, 3.fits...)

Tags: python

здраствуйте, мне надо чтобы вот ето выполнялось с множеством файлов(2.fits, 3.fits, 4.fits...)

```
from astride import Streak

streak = Streak('1.fits')
streak.detect()
streak.write_outputs()
```

пробывал с циклом while но почемуто работает только с первым файлом.

```
 n = 1
 while n != 64
 streak = Streak(str(n) + ".fits")
 streak.detect()
 streak.write_outputs()
 n = n+1
```

буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: `с циклом while` добавьте пример, интересно посмотреть :)

Answer (score 0):

Если файлов в папке 64, то так:

```
n = 1
while n <= 64: # Цикл работает пока условие True
    streak = Streak(str(n) + ".fits")
    streak.detect()
    streak.write_outputs()
    n = n+1
```

в твоем случае "while n != 64" - n не равно 64, это False, цикл останавливается.

Comment: Такое лучше через `for n in range` делать - код понятнее, и одна строка кода вместо трёх.

Comment: @CrazyElf, alexsnov, а что, разве в дубликате нет всех этих вариантов?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Ленюсь смотреть дубликаты )  Закрыл

Comment: @CrazyElf, злые языки поговаривают, что изобретатель первого велосипеда тоже всего лишь поленился заглянуть в труды [леонардо да винчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8)